# Potential problem with multicollinearity?

Tags: least-squares, multicollinearity

I am trying to figure out what happens to my results if I unintentionally introduced multicollinearity.

I have an unadjusted version of this regression that includes an interaction term. The unadjusted regression is $Y = X_0 + X_1*X_2 + \epsilon$ -- where $X_1$ is my treatment and $X_2$ is a potential confounder - party ID - that I made a dummy variable (0/1) from seven categories. In essence, I used case_when and set 1 = party A and 0 = party not A. The goal was to preserve power since I had a small sample and doing and interaction with the categorical variable (with 5 categories) would have been underpowered.

The adjusted regression does the same but also included a $X_3$ term with items that made-up the dummy variable - thus, instead of 0/1 it includes the original categorical variable with 'strong republican, republican, indep...' -> $Y = X_0 + X_1*X_2 + X_3 + \epsilon$. I think I originally included $X_3$ to make sure that none of the group within $X_2$ could have been driving the effects (maybe silly looking back on it).

The coefficients for the adjusted and unadjusted regression are basically the same, except for the constant. None of the VIF are above 5 - though the one for $X_1*X_2$ is 4.7 in both cases.

Conceptually, what happens when I introduce multicollinearity with an interaction term? Does something like this - introducing the same variable as dummy (interaction) and categorical (by itself) cause problems other than on SEs?

Comment: I've modified your question to replace $B_i$ with $X_i$. We use $X_i$ for the features (which we know) and $\beta_i$ for the regression coefficients (which we estimate).

Comment: About your model in particular: Why introduce the dummy variable in the first place? This implies loss of information since the categories seem to be ordered.

Comment: *"and X2 is a potential confounder - like party ID, race or age group - that I made a dummy variable (0/1) from seven categories."* This is unclear. You have a multitude of variables that you turn into a single dummy variable? Why?

Comment: *"a X3 term with items that made-up the dummy variable"* How do you include the items, like party ID, race or age group, in a single variable?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus - it was only one variable, the description was just to to provide examples. But it was only party ID - sorry for the confusion

Comment: @dipetkov - I had good substantive reasons to do so; the main one was a loss of power with the other categories if split. With the interaction, I was combining categories together to focus on the effect of the treatment on group of interest vs not group of interest. But now I am worried about the effects of potential multicollinearity - which I assume I have here - I think my SEs may not be accurate, but the coefficients should still be OK right?

Comment: The description of the data and the transformations you applied remain unclear; same for the goal of the analysis. What is the group of interest? It will be easiest to explain by showing us some of the data. You also ask whether the results make sense but show no results.

Comment: @dipetkov - I can add some more information to the post that will hopefully make it clearer (first time posting) but I probably cannot include the data. My question was mainly conceptual -> what happens to the interaction terms if I unintentionally introduce multicollinearity? ---

Comment: What do you mean by 'effects of multicollinearity'?